Error in Selenium Scraper on Inactive Cloud VM: Button Click Failure
I’m running a Selenium web scraper on a cloud VM as a daily task using the task scheduler. The scraper functions perfectly when I’m actively using the VM or even when the VM is minimized. However, I encounter an error when I completely log out or leave the VM inactive. The error specifically occurs when the scraper attempts to click a button on a webpage.
Example of the Issue:
When the VM is active or minimized, the scraper successfully clicks buttons and performs tasks as expected.
When I am not logged in or the VM is inactive, the script throws an error at the line where it attempts to click a button, disrupting the scheduled tasks.
Has anyone faced a similar issue? What can I do to ensure the scraper continues to operate correctly even when the VM is not in use? Any suggestions or troubleshooting tips would be greatly appreciated!
